# jQuery - Select a random option after 10 seconds if user does not choose one

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jQuery.

I've a group of 5 divs and the final user will have 10 seconds to click on one of these divs.
If he don't do that, randomly one of them will be choose.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you do for now?

Comment: it (http://jsfiddle.net/vitorboccio/X4242/)
just added "add class" and "remove class" to see if its really working

Comment: @user3025104 Questions asking for code/problems with code should have the code in the question itself. Please edit your question with the link under your question and add the relevant code to the question. Tell us what happened and why that isn't what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a combination of `Math.random()` and `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $("div")[index].click();
}, 10000);
```